# Most efficient way to search through an object and array locating match

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, lodash

i have 2 object/arrays:

```
var objA = {
    Red Chair : "DC10291",
    USBDongle : "USKI82322",
}

var arrayB = [
   {
       field: "Yellow Banana",
       id: "Yellow Banana"
   },
   {
       field: "Red Chair",
       id: "Red Chair"
   },
   {
       field: "Garden",
       id: "Garden"
   }
]
```

What i am trying to do is, that if a `KEY` from `objA`, e.g. `Red Chair`, is present in `arrayB`, then remove it from `arrayB`.

I have done this:

```
var arrayClone = _.cloneDeep(arrayB);
var removeThese = [];

Object.keys(arrayClone).forEach(function(p) {
    removeThese.push(p)
});


removeThese.forEach(function(remove) {
    arrayB.forEach(function(item) {
        if(item.id === remove) {
            delete objA[remove];
        }
    });
 });
```

The above works as expected, however is this the most effieicnt? Reasone i ask is because looping throuhg and array within an array loop doesnt feel the best practice? And will have performance impact

Comment: do you want the `arrayB` array to remain unchanged and remove matched properties from `objA` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply filter it, like this

```
_.filter(arrayB, obj => !objA.hasOwnProperty(obj.field))
// [ { field: 'Yellow Banana', id: 'Yellow Banana' },
//  { field: 'Garden', id: 'Garden' } ]
```

This uses ES2015's Arrow function syntax. You can write the same with a normal function like this

```
arrayB.filter(function(obj) {
  return !objA.hasOwnProperty(obj.field);
});
// [ { field: 'Yellow Banana', id: 'Yellow Banana' },
//  { field: 'Garden', id: 'Garden' } ]
```

We are basically filtering out all the objects whose `field` value is a key in `objA`.

Comment: Thanks, sorry this is new... how do it delete after filter?

Comment: @OamPsy You mean, you want to remove the values from `arrayB` also?

Comment: Sorry, i mean how can i then delete the matches from objA

Comment: @OamPsy That is exactly it does, right... See the sample output in the code comments

Comment: Ok, but in your example above... i understand where arrayb and objA have come from, but what about obj?

Comment: @OamPsy It is a parameter of the Anonymous function which we pass to the filter function.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to keep the original arrayB and get a reduced version of it according to your condition then `Array.prototype.reduce()` does that with O(n) time complexity. However if you would like to perform this operation in place then `Array.prototype.reduceRight()` does that with O(n) time complexity.

```js
var objA = {
    "Red Chair" : "DC10291",
    "USBDongle" : "USKI82322",
},

 arrayB = [
   {
       field: "Yellow Banana",
       id: "Yellow Banana"
   },
   {
       field: "Red Chair",
       id: "Red Chair"
   },
   {
       field: "Garden",
       id: "Garden"
   }
],

 arrayC = arrayB.reduce((p,c) => !objA[c.field] ? p.concat(c) : p, []);
 console.log(arrayC);
 arrayB.reduceRight((p,c,i,a) => (p[c.field] && a.splice(i,1),p),objA);
 console.log(arrayB);
```